# In angular updating one variable inexplicably updates another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly

I am using angular and plotly to plot either the raw data or a moving average. I have the moving average working but I am running into an issue with assigning variables. I retrieve an array of user objects which each have an x and y key with arrays associated with them.

```
$scope.init=function(){
   $rootScope.page='companyResults';
   $scope.isPlotlyDone = false;
   $scope.moving = false;

   var refresh = function () {
     incidentService.dayWiseTripsByUser(...).then(function (plotArray){
        $scope.unaffectedPlot = plotArray;
        $scope.movingAveragePlot = allMoving(plotArray);
        console.log($scope.unaffectedPlot[0].y);
        console.log($scope.movingAveragePlot[0].y);

     });
   };

   refresh();
 }
```

Im that code block, I would expect that `$scope.unaffectedPlot[0].y` and `$scope.movingAveragePlot[0].y` would have different arrays since I ran the latter through the following set of functions. The curious thing is that both $scope variables are synced, so if I run the second through `allMoving` the `unaffectedPlot` variable also gets smoothed and neither get synced obviously if I don't call `allMoving`. What am I missing about Angular? What is a good way to have a moving average work with a toggle? My plan is to show one variable or the other depending on if a button is clicked.

```
var d3_numeric = function(x) {
  return !isNaN(x);
}

var d3sum = function(array, f) {
  var s = 0,
      n = array.length,
      a,
      i = -1;
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
   // zero and null are equivalent
    while (++i < n) if (d3_numeric(a = +array[i])) s += a;
  } else {
    while (++i < n) if (d3_numeric(a = +f.call(array, array[i], i))) s += a;
  }
  return s;
};

var movingWindowAvg = function (arr, step) {
  return arr.map(function (_, idx) {
      var wnd = arr.slice(idx - step, idx + step + 1);
      var result = d3sum(wnd) / wnd.length; if (isNaN(result)) { result = _; }
      return result;
  });
};

var allMoving = function(pltArray) {
  var movingArray = [];
  pltArray.forEach(function(plot){
    var oneMoving = plot;
    oneMoving.y = movingWindowAvg(plot.y, 5);
    movingArray.push(oneMoving);

  });
  return movingArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually isn't an angular issue. I had to test it some since I didn't see what was going on either.

When you wrote

```
oneMoving.y = blah
```

you were actually altering the contents of plot for each element and in turn altering the contents of plotArray unintentionally (since plot is an object)
So you are only creating a reference variable when you say 'var onMoving = plot' )

To outright solve your problem you can clone plot but that isn't so clean of a process

One easy yet dirty way is

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) thread

I threw together a shotty example that captures what was going wrong for you

```
var array = [{one:1, two:2},{one:1, two:2},{one:1, two:2}],
    copyArray = array,
    newArr = doStuff(array)
function doStuff(a) {
    var otherNewArr = []
    a.forEach(function(ae) {
        var aVar = ae
        aVar.one = 5
        otherNewArr.push(aVar)
    })
    return otherNewArr
}
console.log(copyArray,newArr)
```

And to fix it just replace

```
var aVar = ae
```

with

```
var aVar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ae))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution totally solved the problem and I appreciate the example that you wrote. Javascript is a little funny sometimes, huh?

Comment: no problem! glad that fixed it, too bad there isn't a clean and easy way to deep copy javascript objects